# Extracting Android App ID from URL

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract Android application ID from URL.

Examples of URLs are:

`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.mini.native`

`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.mini.native&referrer=xxxx`

And I want to get `com.opera.mini.native` substrings form both URLs.

I tried to create regex to parse ID, but unsuccessfully:

`^.+details\?id=(.+)&?.+`

The problem is that regex returns `com.opera.mini.native&referrer=xxxx` for second case (for 1st URL it works fine).

How I can change regex to achieve my goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you made `&` as optional.

```
".+\\bdetails\\?id=([^&]+)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex can be:

```
(?<=[?&]id=)[^&]+
```

[ResEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dB3hG0/1)